# How to get browser's height from CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using scrollbar function in my div tag.

I want to set the scroll bar to my browser height.

I am trying to get the value like this.

javascript

```
<script>
var height = window.innerHeight;
</script>
```

css code

```
    <style>
      .kryesore {
               overflow-y: scroll;
               overflow-y:auto;
               height:height-320px ;
            }
    </style>
```

[here I have created JSFIDDLE code](https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/pL1wqaj1/)

I want to show the table within the header and footer without browser scrollbar.

the scroll bar should show only in the table that is my requirement.

if I get browser window height I will subtract it by 320. then it will fix my issue and the browser windows scroll bar also not shown so that i want to get the javascript value to css.

can any tell me the correct solution.

Comment: you'll have to make changes to style attribut of the element. something like `document.getElementByClassName('krysore').style.height = height`

Comment: But beware, it'll be inline style and will take precedence over any css specified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via CSS only.
I don't know what is your CSS class for scrollbar, thus I'm using `scrollbar` class.

```
<style>
  .scrollbar {
           overflow-y: auto;
           height: calc(100vh - 320px);
        }
</style>
```

`100vh` is equal to browser's height, `calc` function can dynamically calculate such CSS values.

Comment: I guess it's trivial but just in case: the space around the minus sign ( - ) are required

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference JS variables through CSS, but you can change CSS with JS.

Try:

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('.kryesore').style.height = height;
```

Comment: Hi stefanBob: i got this error "Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: :@ stefanBob: i have updated my question now you will understand clearly.